# Django NameError in project urls.py

Tags: python, django, nameerror

I apologise for yet another simple Django question but I cannot find what I'm after.

Project: footystats
App: stats

What I'm trying to do is defer all URL mapping to the app so I have url.py in footystats which contains the following:

```
    ..
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
                           url(r'^', include(stats.urls), namespace = 'stats')
    )
    ..
```

When I try to open the main page I get the following error:

NameError at /main/

name 'stats' is not defined

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:            **redacted**/main/
Django Version:     1.6.1
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value: name 'stats' is not defined

Exception Location:     c:\django\footystats\footystats\urls.py in , line 8
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path: ['c:\django\footystats',
 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django',
 'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip',
 'C:\Python27\DLLs',
 'C:\Python27\lib',
 'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win',
 'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
 'C:\Python27',
 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages']

Is this enough to go on? Do you need more information?

Thanks

Comment: did you import stats yet? if not you can import it or change stats.urls for 'stats.urls'

Comment: Meh I knew it was stupid. Thank you! Do you think I should get rid of this question? Its a bit specific

Comment: @Igrevenl Yeah, i think it's too localized. You can just accept the answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you imported stats yet? if not you can **import it** or change `stats.urls` for `'stats.urls'`